# How do I start a Vim syntax-region at the very start of the document, while also allowing a keyword-match in that same position?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

Thanks to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096093/31897), I've managed to assign a syntax-region to my document that starts *at the very start (*[`\%^`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%25%5E)*) of the document*:

```
syn region menhirDeclarations start=/\%^./rs=e-1 end=/%%/me=s-1
```

To get that to work, the start pattern had to match the very first character of the document. That is, the above won't work with just `start=/\%^/`; it needs that last `.` (The match, when successful, then *excludes* that character; but it has to actually match before that happens …)

Problem is, any [`:syn-keyword`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-keyword) match at the same location — even one lower in [`:syn-priority`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-priority) — is going to preempt my above region-match. Basically, this means I can't have *any `keyword`* that's allowed to match at the start of the document, or that keyword, when so placed, will prevent the above "whole-top-of-the-document" region from matching at all.

Concrete example. With the following syntax:

```
syn keyword menhirDeclarationKeyword %parameter %token " ...
syn region menhirDeclarations start=/\%^./rs=e-1 end=/%%/me=s-1
```

… the document …

```
%token <blah> blah
blah blah blah
```

… will not contain the requisite `menhirDeclarations` region, because `menhirDeclarationKeyword` matched at the very first character, consuming it, and preventing `menhirDeclarations` from matching.

I can bypass this by declaring *everything* in the syntax definition as a [`:syn-match`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-match) or [`:syn-region`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-region), and defining the above region very last … but that's probably a performance problem, and more importantly, really difficult to manage.

**tl;dr:** Is there any way to match a region at the very start of the document, *and* allow keywords to match at the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the keywords, you have to make them `contained`. Else, Vim's syntax rules will always give them precedence, and they won't allow your region(s) to match. If I remember correctly from your last question, the whole document is parsed as a sequence of different regions; that would be great. Else, you have to create new regions or matches for those parts of the document that are not yet covered, but may also contain keywords.

```
syn keyword menhirDeclarationKeyword contained %parameter %token
syn region menhirDeclarations start=/\%^%token\>/rs=e-1 end=/%%/me=s-1 contains=menhirDeclarationKeyword
```

---

If that isn't feasible, you indeed have to use `:syntax match` instead:

```
syn match menhirDeclarationKeyword "\<%token\>"
```

Don't assume that this will be slower; measure it via [`:help :syntime`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyntime), on various complex input files.

The "difficult to manage" part can be addressed via Vimscript metaprogramming. For example, you can keep all keywords in a list and build the definitions dynamically with a loop:

```
for s:keyword in ['parameter', 'token']
    execute printf('syntax match menhirDeclarationKeyword "\<%%%s\>"', s:keyword)
endfor
```

Comment: This is an awesome answer. Yeah, needed them outside regions (specifically, I’m trying to highlight *erroneous* tokens — once’s where they shouldn’t be, including outside valid regions). And TIL about `:syntime` and that awesome metaprogramming trick!